# Union of rectangles in a 2d tiled world

Tags: c++, stl, computational-geometry, 2d-games

I am trying to find the bounding polygon of a set of adjacent cells(row,col) ( convertable to rectangles) in a 2d tiled world.

Processing the cells in a for loop and using the neighbourhood property of the adjacent cells I could eliminate all internal edges and store the rest of the edges. 
The edges are stored in std::vector;

Now I need to merge the edges where there is a common vertex and slope is the same.
After merging the edges I need to make the bounding polygon, starting from a vertex going counter clockwise.

Please help to find a method to make it possible.

Comment: A draw about the problem could improve the question

Comment: do you mean [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uivw8ff7ftb2o6/2013-10-04%2013.36.20.png)? (The yellow are the input tiles, and the red is the output polygon)

Comment: @Manu343726 yes you are right. here is the scenario https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0vaabd3nmgi8is/unionof2dcells.png

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a simple algorithm to achieve that.

Consider we have this as input:

```
 |   |   |   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+---+---+-
 |   |   |   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+---+---+-
 |   |   | a |   |   |
-+---+---+---+---+---+-
 |   | b | c | d |   |
-+---+---+---+---+---+-
 |   |   | e |   |   |
-+---+---+---+---+---+-
 |   |   |   |   |   |
```

Where `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` are our input tiles stored as a vector of pairs (Coordinates):

```
std::vector<std::pair<unsigned,unsigned>> tiles;
```

What we want is this:

```
 |   |   |   |   |   |
-+---+---+---+---+---+-
 |   |   |   |   |   |
-+---+---*---*---+---+-
 |   |   |   |   |   |
-+---*---*   *---*---+-
 |   |           |   |
-+---*---*   *---*---+-
 |   |   |   |   |   |
-+---+---*---*---+---+-
 |   |   |   |   |   |
```

The algorithm works as follows:

1. Build an array of booleans enclosing the entire set of tiles. You have to trasverse the set to find the bounds of that rectangle. Set as true the positions of the array which represent a tile of the set, and as false otherwise.
   The output in the example will be (T is `true` and f is `false`):

   ```
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | f |  
   +---+---+---+  
   | T | T | T |  
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | f ]  
   +---+---+---+
   ```
2. Now you have to traverse the border of the hull polygon. Start at the first element marked as `true` in the flag array and trasverse the vertices in the same direction until you reach the first vertex again, using this rules:

   - If the two tiles in front of the current direction/position are false, turn clockwise and **add the vertex to the output list (polygon)**:
     (`*` are vertices added to the polygon, `X` the current vertex, the arrow the current direction)

     ```
     +---+---+---+  
     | f | f | f |  
     *---+---X---+ --->   
     | T | T | f |  
     *---+---+---+  
     | f | T | f ]  
     +---+---+---+  

     goes to

     +---+---+---+  
     | f | f | f |  |
     *---+---*---+  |
     | T | T | f |  v
     *---+---X---+  
     | f | T | f ]  
     +---+---+---+
     ```
   - If one tile is false and one true, go in the same direction (Note that true-false or false-true means you are in a border):

     ```
     +---+---+---+  
     | f | f | f | |   
     *---+---*---+ |  
     | T | T | f | v  
     *---+---X---+  
     | f | T | f ]  
     +---+---+---+  

     goes to

     +---+---+---+  
     | f | f | f |  |
     *---+---*---+  |
     | T | T | f |  v
     *---+---+---+  
     | f | T | f ]  
     +---+---X---+
     ```
   - If both tiles are true, turn counter-clockwise and **add the vertex to the output list** (Note that true-true means you have reached part of the set of tiles, a "wall"):

     ```
     +---+---+---+  
     | f | f | f | |   
     *---+---*---+ |  
     | T | T | f | v  
     *---+---X---+  
     | f | T | T ]  
     +---+---+---+  

     goes to

     +---+---+---+  
     | f | f | f |  
     +---+---*---+  
     | T | T | f |  --->
     +---+---*---X  
     | f | T | T ]  
     +---+---+---+
     ```

## Considerations:

### tilemap coordinates vs flag-array coordinates

The flag-array represents the rectangle region of the tilemap where the tiles are placed. So the tilemap-coordinates of its first element (tile) is `(left,top)` where `left` is the minimum x-coordinate of the selected set of tiles, and `top` is the minimum y-coordinate of the selected set of tiles.

In the second step of the agorithm, you trasverse the frontier (border) of the set of tiles, using the array as a guide. Note that what you really trasverse is that array, so **you have to translate the coordinates from flag-coordinates (logical coordinates) to tilemap-coordinates (physical coordinates)** to store the vertices of the polygon. Of course thats easy.

Also note that the algorithm abstract steps trasverse **vertices of edges (physical tile coordinates), not logical-coordinates**. You have to be sure what *"I'm in that vertex"* means and what *"advance"* and "*turn*" mean in terms of flag-array coordinates.

### Border conditions and the front-tiles check

We have defined three rules to advance along the border of the set of tiles. We have used the flag-array as a guide to decide what to do (Advance, turn clockwise, or turn counter-clockwise). Note that when the current vertex is in the border of the array, **you could (you should) consider that it have neighbour tiles with a false value**.

For example:

```
+---+---+---+  
| f | f | f |  |  
*---+---*---+  |  
| T | T | f |  v
*---+---+---+  
| f | T | f ]  
+---+---X---+
```

goes to

```
+---+---+---+  
| f | f | f |  
*---+---*---+  <--
| T | T | f |  
*---+---+---+  
| f | T | f ]  
+---X---*---+
```

exactly as if it was this:

```
+---+---+---+  
| f | f | f |  |  
*---+---*---+  |  
| T | T | f |  v
*---+---+---+  
| f | T | f ]  
+---+---X---+
| f | f | f |  
*---*---*---+
```

### Possible optimisations

The first step computes the flag array because the algorithm takes the set of tiles selected as a vector. If your tile engine supports it, you could add a property to the tiles (`bool selected`) and pass the tilemap directly, **avoiding the computation and the vertex cooordinates transformations**.

## Example

Given this flag-array:

```
+---+---+---+  
| T | f | f |    
+---+---+---+    
| T | T | T |
+---+---+---+  
| f | T | T |  
+---+---+---+
```

The execution works as follows **(Note that the drawings are the state AFTER the execution of the step)**:

1. Find the first `true` tile. In this case `(0,0)`. So we start at one of its vertex (bottom-left vertex, looking upwards, for example. Note that because its the first true tile, you could use that vertex being sure that it belongs to the polygon. So **add that first vertex to the polygon**):

   ```
   Current position: (0,1)
   Polygon: {(0,1)} 

   +---+---+---+ ^ 
   | T | f | f | |  
   X---+---+---+ |    
   | T | T | T |
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | T |  
   +---+---+---+
   ```
2. Start the trasverse. In this case, the front tiles are `false-true`, so **advance**:

   ```
   Current position: (0,0)
   Polygon: {(0,1)} 

   X---+---+---+ ^ 
   | T | f | f | |  
   *---+---+---+ |    
   | T | T | T |
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | T |  
   +---+---+---+
   ```
3. The front tiles are `false-false` (We are in a border), so **turn clockwise and add the vertex**:

   ```
   Current position: (1,0)
   Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0)} 

   *---X---+---+ 
   | T | f | f |   
   *---+---+---+     
   | T | T | T | --->
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | T |  
   +---+---+---+
   ```
4. Now the fron-tiles are `false-false` (One is out of the array, and the other is `false`).  **turn clockwise and add the vertex**:

   ```
   Current position: (1,1)
   Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0)} 

   *---*---+---+ 
   | T | f | f | | 
   *---X---+---+ |   
   | T | T | T | v
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | T |  
   +---+---+---+
   ```
5. The two front-tiles are `true`: **Turn counter-clockwise and add the vertex**:

   ```
   Current position: (1,2)
   Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)} 

   *---*---+---+ 
   | T | f | f |   
   *---*---X---+     
   | T | T | T | --->
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | T |  
   +---+---+---+
   ```
6. One tile is `false` and the other is `true`: **Advance**:

   ```
   Current position: (1,3)
   Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)} 

   *---*---+---+ 
   | T | f | f |   
   *---*---+---X     
   | T | T | T | --->
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | T |  
   +---+---+---+
   ```
7. Two `false` tiles (Both out of array): **Turn clockwise and add the vertex**:

   ```
   Current position: (2,3)
   Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(3,1)} 

   *---*---+---+ 
   | T | f | f | | 
   *---*---+---* |   
   | T | T | T | v
   +---+---+---X  
   | f | T | T |  
   +---+---+---+
   ```
8. One `true` and one `false`(Out of array): **Advance**:

   ```
   Current position: (3,3)
   Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(3,1)} 

   *---*---+---+ 
   | T | f | f | | 
   *---*---+---* |   
   | T | T | T | v
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | T |  
   +---+---+---X
   ```
9. Two `false`(Out of array) front-tiles: **Turn clockwise and add the vertex**:

   ```
   Current position: (2,3)
   Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(3,1),(3,3)} 

   *---*---+---+ 
   | T | f | f |  
   *---*---+---*    
   | T | T | T | <---
   +---+---+---+  
   | f | T | T |  
   +---+---X---*
   ```
10. `true-false` (One `true` and one out of bounds): **Advance**:

    ```
    Current position: (1,3)
    Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(3,1),(3,3)} 

    *---*---+---+ 
    | T | f | f |  
    *---*---+---*    
    | T | T | T | <---
    +---+---+---+  
    | f | T | T |  
    +---X---+---*
    ```
11. `false-false` (One `false` and one out of bounds): **Turn clockwise and add the vertex**:

    ```
    Current position: (1,2)
    Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(3,1),(3,3),(1,3)} 

    *---*---+---+ 
    | T | f | f | ^ 
    *---*---+---* |   
    | T | T | T | |
    +---X---+---+  
    | f | T | T |  
    +---*---+---*
    ```
12. `true-true` front-tiles: **Turn counter-clockwise and add the vertex**:

    ```
    Current position: (0,2)
    Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(3,1),(3,3),(1,3),(1,2)} 

    *---*---+---+ 
    | T | f | f | 
    *---*---+---*    
    | T | T | T | <---
    X---*---+---+  
    | f | T | T |  
    +---*---+---*
    ```
13. `false-false` front-tiles: **Turn clockwise and add the vertex**:

    ```
    Current position: (0,1)
    Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(3,1),(3,3),(1,3),(1,2),(0,2)} 

    *---*---+---+ 
    | T | f | f | ^ 
    X---*---+---* |   
    | T | T | T | |
    *---*---+---+  
    | f | T | T |  
    +---*---+---*
    ```
14. The current vertex is the first vertex of the polygon: **The execution have finished**. The result is as follows:

    ```
    Polygon: {(0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(3,1),(3,3),(1,3),(1,2),(0,2)} 

    *---* 
    |   |  
    *   *-------*    
    |           | 
    *---*       |  
        |       |  
        *-------*
    ```

Comment: I couldn't validate the example scenario map with this method. Can you prove its correctness with this input { {T, F, F} {T,T,T} {F,T,T} }

Comment: the input is the rows of the flag map of the example scenario.

Comment: @manojmj I have added a complete example using that as input.

Answer (score 0):

Because of tiles, this is a 'special case' of finding boundary polygon. I would go with some simple approach.

Tile (x,y) consist of vertices [(x,y), (x+1,y), (x+1,y+1), (x,y+1)]. Vertex is a part of boundary polygon if it is in 1, 2 or 3 tiles. To find vertices on boundary it is enough to count number of tiles it is in. For that it is enough to pass through tiles and increment vertex appearance count for tile 4 vertices. Vertices with tile count 1, 2 or 3 are on the boundary polygon.

To order vertices it is enough to start from some vertex on a boundary and look for a neighbouring vertex that is also on a boundary. To traverse vertices in same direction it is important to take a care of direction order of neighbouring vertices to check. E.g. if last vertex is on -x, than order of directions to check is +y, +x, -y.

Since direction of last edge is known, if next edge is in the same direction than that vertex is for a removal. If region is simple connected, than removal can be known also from tile count. If tile count of a vertex is 2 than vertex is for removal.

For now we don't have guarantee that order is clockwise. That can be check by checking (some of) upper-most edge(s) is it in clockwise direction. If it is not, than reverse polygon.